# How to add a Column with Button Control in Grid View?

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

I am working on windows forms using DevExpress. I bonded my DevExpress GridView on Form_Load.

```
private void DXRemarks_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
}
```

This draws all the columns in my gridView. Now, I want to add a column consisting of a button control to get the value of a particular row  on button's click from that gridView. I don't know how to do that (can't bind both my data and button together).
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q366274

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the button altogether by instead using the `_CellDoubleClick`event instead.

for the event use:

```
gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[n].Value
```

where "n" is the cell reference of the value you want to retrieve (starting from 0)

then either use `ToString()` or a convert to get the value you need from the cell - depending on what the type of value you want to retrieve is.

You can make this easier by setting the `SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect` and making the cells uneditable - thus making a double click on any row provide the value

If you are dead set on using a button to obtain the value, then

`gridView.SelectedCells[n].Value`

assigned to the onclick event will get the value of cell "n" from your datagridview. As above, you can then use ToString() or a convert method to access the value